# Using closures as constructors in javascript objects best practice

Tags: javascript, constructor, closures

This is more of a general question about best practices. I understand that javascript is a prototypical language and doesn't have constructors in the traditional sense, but is there anything wrong with using closures to create a constructor like you might find in a more class based language?  What I mean is something like this:

```
var foo = function () {
    this.bar = undefined; //this.bar is a field not a method
    (function (that) {

        //lots of processing needs to happen to determine what 
        //the value of bar should be

    })(this); // passing in this give us access to this.bar
}

foo.prototype.getbar = function () {
    return this.bar
}
```

I found this useful when turning the html2canvas library into an angularjs service, but wanted to know if this was bad practice.

Comment: But JavaScript *does* have constructors.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you're doing, the question is why you're doing it, do you need an IIFE, if not there's no reason to add one ?

Comment: In the context of what I was doing, the html2canvas library was written as one IIFE placing its variables on the window object.  What I needed to do was turn it into a class to make it easy to use as an angular service.  What I eneded up doing was taking the variables on the window object and making them properties of a class instead.  Then I used an IIFE to do most of the processing that needed to be done, similar to how constructors are written in other languages.

Comment: Your syntax is invalid. You can't have `this` as a function parameter. Your "closure" is just an immediately invoked function. There's nothing terribly special happening there other than creating a variable scope.